# Update field using Lightning Components

Tags: lightning, field-update

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to developing on the Salesforce platform. I'm building a simple Lightning component where I want to query and display fields from a custom object, and then allow the user to update the field and submit their changes, thus updating the field on the object. Right now I'm simply trying to update the Name field on my custom object just to get something working and then build from there.

It appears that when I click the Save button, the save function fires on the client side with no errors, but nothing is written to the actual object. That's what I've been able to garner so far.

I've followed a few Trailhead courses and read documentation on creating the sample Expense App, but I know I'm not connecting the dots correctly somewhere. Here's what I have built:

**get4Dassessments.apxc**

```
public class get4Dassessments {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static X4D_Assessment__c getAssessments(){
        return (X4D_Assessment__c) Database.query( ' SELECT Name, Customer_Acquisition__c FROM X4D_Assessment__c LIMIT 1 ' )[0];
    }

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static X4D_Assessment__c saveAssessment(X4D_Assessment__c assessment){
        upsert assessment;
        return assessment;
    }  

}
```

**sparkAssessmentController.js**

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAssessments");

    action.setParams({
        "assessmentId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });

    // Register the callback function
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.assessments", data.getReturnValue());
    });

    // Invoke the service
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}, 
save : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.saveAssessment");
    var name = component.get("v.assessments.Name"); //gets value of field

    console.log("Name:" + name);
    action.setParams({"Name": name});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    console.log('save ran');

}
})
```

**sparkAssessment.cmp**

```
 <!-- controller: get4Dassessments references the get4Dassessments.apxc Apex class -->
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" controller="get4Dassessments">

<!-- This event handler calls the init client-side controller to handle initialization. -->
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}" />

<!-- make the list of assessments accessible to your component. -->
<aura:attribute name="assessments" type="X4D_Assessment__c" />

<!-- define the recordId attribute -->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

<!-- reference LDS static resource -->
<ltng:require styles="/resource/slds103/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>

 <form>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="client"
                  label="{!$ObjectType.X4D_Assessment__c.fields.Name.Label}"
                  class="form-control"
                  value="{!v.assessments.Name}"
                  placeholder="Put answer here"
    />
    <br />
    <ui:button class="form-control" aura:id="button" label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
</form>

 </aura:component>
```

Again, I'm a new Salesforce developer and I'm fairly certain I must be missing something obvious. Thank you in advance for any tips or guidance you can provide.

Comment: Hi Lindsay, does the org or sandbox you're trying this in have Lightning Locker enabled? There seem to be some finicky issues with binding to object properties right now that were not a problem on API v36 before Locker. Other possible diagnostic steps: Try console logging the data you're about to pass to the server. Try adding a callback to the save function and logging the response to see what actually comes back.

Comment: @CharlesT thanks for the tips! Turns out I had a flaw in my logic when I was passing my object through the save function. I'm not surprised I figured it out after deciding to post my question publicly.  Thanks for the help and for the diagnostic advice as well.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. One little tip that I didn't even know was part of JS until I found it in Trailhead was the `debugger;` command. Toss it in the middle of any code and if the developer console is open in your browser the code will pause there. This allows you to explore in the developer console which variables contain what at that point in the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had a flaw in my logic in the save function. Here's what wound up working for me:

```
save : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.saveAssessment");
    var assessments = component.get("v.assessments");

    action.setParams({"assessment": assessments});
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    console.log('save ran');

}
```