# How to update a field on Lead object with Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, field-update, crud

I was playing around with Lightning Trail Head Examples and couldn't figure out how to update a record. When I asked google Yoda master, master referred me here,to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96793/how-to-update-a-field-with-lightning-components). I was able to replicate this for 'Account' but not for 'Lead'. 
I checked my console logs, I see there was an error related to loading script(console log error : because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "*script-src 'self' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/*"). I'm not trying to load any scripts, I'm simply minding my business with Lead.

I followed each and every step as it is (basically copy pasted and changed it to Lead SObject, posting the code as well.) and I still get nothing. please shed some wisdom of light here.

I really appreciate you taking time to reply :)

### my component

```
<aura:component controller="leadController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lead"  type="Lead" />
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form>
        <ui:inputText aura:id="client"
            label="{!$ObjectType.Lead.fields.Name.Label}"
            class="form-control"
            value="{!v.lead.Name}"
            placeholder="Name"
        />
        <br />
        <ui:button class="form-control" aura:id="button" label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
        <br />
    <br />
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

---

### my client- side  controller:

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('init');
        var action2 = component.get("c.getLead");        
        action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.lead", response.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);
    }, 
    save : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('save:1');
        var action = component.get("c.saveLead");
        var lead = component.get("v.lead");
        action.setParams({
            "lead": lead}
        );
        action.setCallback(this, function() {  console.log('SAVED.');  } );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log('save:end');
    },
})
```

### my apex controller :

```
public with sharing class leadController {

    @AuraEnabled 
     public static Lead getLead(){
        return (Lead) Database.query( ' SELECT Name FROM Lead LIMIT 1 ' )[0];
    }
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static Lead saveLead(Lead lead){
        upsert lead;
        return lead;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in two parts to this question:

1. I realized my company firewall stops some scrips while loading hence i get the error 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/". So its just the company firewall.
2. I found a workaround by following [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127134/update-field-using-lightning-components).